# MongoDB indexing and counting for subdocument

Tags: mongodb

Please give me an advise, how i can resolve my issue.
I have a MongoDB collection "cards" with over 5 million documents. 
Here is example of typycal document in my collection

```
 {
        "_id" : "300465-905543",
        "products" : "00000",
        "groupQuality" : {
                "defQuality" : 100,
                "summQuality" : 92.22
        }
}
```

I need count up quantity of documents with some products and with some value of quality so i tried to use something like this

```
db.cards.count({groupQuality.defQuality : {$gt : 50, $lte : 100}})
```

For improving speed of this operation i created index {groupQuality.defQuality : 1}
It was good decision, count of documents returned fast, but after adding into imbedded document with name "groupQuality" one more group of quality i must create another index for this group.
Quantity of new groups of quality may be huge, so i don't want build index for every new group of quality.
I start thinking about creating index {groupQuality : 1} which will cower all groups of quality in imbedded document. Does it possible in MongoDB?
If i can create such index, how can i  make a query to count up documents with some products and with some value of quality in case using index by groupQuality?
I tryed next query but it always return 0.

```
db.cards.count({ products : "00000", groupQuality : { defQuality : {$gt : 50, $lte : 100}, summQuality : {$gt : 0, $lte : 100}}})
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have nested fields, you need to provide the full path for every field you match instead of providing a nested document:

```
db.cards.count({ 
      "products" : "00000", 
      "groupQuality.defQuality" : {$gt : 50, $lte : 100}, 
      "groupQuality.summQuality" : {$gt : 0, $lte : 100}
})
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but unfortunantely operation time is very long and it is not acceptable for me. I probably still have to use a separate indexes for each group of quality.